# Cycles doesnt render anything with gpu

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu, hardware

When I switch to cycles, I chose my nvidia rtx 2060 (laptop) gpu.
But when I switch to the render viewpoint, the objects are "empty":

[image]

I use the newest Linux mint version
And my driver version is 470.86

Here my preferences:
[image]

Comment: Have you added a material to the cube?  If so, could you add a screenshot of your material shader (from the shader editor) to your question?  What happens if you render the image rather than view it in render preview mode?

Comment: Have you by any chance also installed the cuda toolkit?

Comment: Yes I have. Don't I need something with optiX?

Comment: @MartyFouts, when I render this with the CPU, I get lots of particles and shading effects like expected